# Configuring a SonicWall TZ100 to protect VM (virtual machines) for PCI compliance

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, firewall, pci-dss, pci

I'm currently running VMWare ESX 4 with several virtual machines. One of these VMs needs to be PCI-DSS compliant, and more may need compliance in the future. In other words, I don't want to allow any LAN-LAN traffic. I currently have a SonicWall TZ100 as the firewall for the box. It seems there is a way to block traffic between VMs on the LAN with the PortShield feature, but I have so far failed to get this configured.

So, either of these approaches will work fine for me:

A. setup security for each VM that needs compliance, so that it denies traffic from anywhere else in the LAN.

B. simply block all intra-LAN traffic (I tried to do this with a simple LAN-LAN access
    rule but it didn't block anything).

Comment: Firewalls manage/secure traffic that flows through them. If the LAN to LAN traffic doesn't flow through the firewall then it can't manage/secure it. Is the ESX host connected to one of the firewall interfaces, with your LAN switch connected to another interface?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I believe I'm going to need to create a VLAN in ESX for each VM that needs to be isolated.

Comment: Your Sonicwall has the capability to filter traffic from port to port in the same zone, by default it does permit this, but it is not necessary to define a new zone.

Answer (score 1):

In order to isolate the LANs you must first start at the TZ100. on the selected LAN interface create a new zone, this will seperate the Zones. Once you create your new zone, you'll need to create Access Rule from NEW ZONE->WAN and WAN->NEW ZONE or you wont be able to access the internet. Then continue to your switch and create your Vlan for complete isolation.